# Get bounding rectangle for CGGlyphs of Characters other then letters or numbers

Tags: ios, swift, string, core-text

I am looking for a way to equire character's glyph descent as indicated on the picture:

[image]

The method **needs to work for any given character** (or at least all common unicode characters).

Here is my actual approach (in Swift, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22647439/311865) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21443625/311865) question):

```
let char = "a"
let ctFont = CTFontCreateWithNameAndOptions("HelveticaNeue", 12, nil, nil)
var ctGlyph = CTFontGetGlyphWithName(ctFont, char)
let boundingBox = withUnsafePointer(&ctGlyph) { pointer -> CGRect in
    return CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(ctFont, CTFontOrientation.OrientationDefault, pointer, nil, 1)
}
```

Descent I need is then simply equal to `-boundingBox.origin.y`.
This approach works nicely for letter and number and number characters (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21497660/311865) for graphical representation).

The problem is that for everything other then letters or numbers (for example: `.,#')*`) it I get the same bounding rectangle: `{x:0.612, y:0.012, w:4.908, h:8.532}`. That is obviously incorrect.

How can I get the bonding rectangle of the descent directly for all characters?

Comment: Code samples are very much prefered in Swift. Thank you

Comment: Check the return argument of `CTFontGetGlyphWithName()` for `.notdef` as mentioned in the documentation: "if the glyph name is not recognized, the `.notdef` glyph [is returned]"

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist You are right that is the bug. Make it an answer and I will accept it.